# Sending push notifications with SNS but not receiving notification on Android device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Does anyone know how to send push notifications with SNS? I am using the JavaScript SDK. I have read the documentation and I think I am following everything. I get confirmation that the message was sent:
Push notification sent successfully!!!!

```
{
ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'XXXXXX1b-5d0d-91d6-5eb8255d7400' },
MessageId: 'XXXXXX-5071-b0bb-bb5225ca097c'
}
```

However, I am not receiving the notification on my real Android device.

I do get the notifications when sent from the AWS SNS Console using this as the message:

```
{
"GCM": "{ \"notification\": {\"title\": \"Test\", \"body\": \"It works\" }}"
}
```

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7Dym.png)

Comment: Can you share sample JavaScript code snippet that you are using and it's not working as expected?

Answer (score -1):

Use below approaches,
1)You can easily send text messages to devices by using the AWS SDK. I have not used JavaScript - however here is the Java V2 example that does send messages to my IPHONE.

```
 https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/sns/src/main/java/com/example/sns/PublishTextSMS.java?fbclid=IwAR1meS4K0goj84rzretAqrceRpZnN3mNC5IxrFvEvHVC-f_Ic-Ds_uUsZ84
```

2. Recommend taking a look at Pinpoint for most Push notification and SMS use cases. Especially customer facing apps

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/mobile-push.html?fbclid=IwAR0aXUzpkRykn0fzUteZvSw8wI-_R_ri5PfgHvC8SkcA6-kuy0_nLOTxiT8
```